# How to troubleshoot Windows error #10057 Socket is not connected at the networking level?

Tags: windows, socket

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2 says, that the cause of #10057 is

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is
>   not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using sendto) no
>   address was supplied. Any other type of operation might also return
>   this error—for example, setsockopt setting SO_KEEPALIVE if the
>   connection has been reset.

As a programmer I know what it means - I should bind socket (via `connect` or `accept` API commands) before trying to call any further (e.g. `send` of `receive`) operations on this socket. As my implementation uses Delphi Indy libraries, I am aware of the problems with `connected` function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852359/tcpclient-connected-problem-in-delphi-indy . But I am already controlling all that in my software and it works great in many network environments. But one local network access almost constantly (in 90% of cases) generated #10057 error.

So - it can not be programming error, it should be something with network setup. So - my question is - how can I troubleshoot network for catching #10057 error?

Maybe antivirus is blocking application or access of application on that port and such manifests appears as #10057?